# What's the right way to configure Nginx for MinIO server running as a docker service

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, minio

I am just trying to proxy pass from Nginx to Docker Minio service; however, with my current nginx config file, it's not working as expected and keeps loading when I browse any Minio buckets from the Minio console (web interface). Note that the minio server is working fine when it is browsed from local network. The current nginx config file for the minio docker service is as follows:

Nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name s3.mysite.com;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name s3.mysite.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/s3.mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/s3.mysite.com/privkey.pem;

    # To allow special characters in headers
    ignore_invalid_headers off;
    # Allow any size file to be uploaded.
    # Set to a value such as 1000m; to restrict file size to a specific value
    client_max_body_size 0;
    # To disable buffering
    proxy_buffering off;

    # Proxy requests to the bucket "photos" to MinIO server running on port 9000
    location /blog/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        # Default is HTTP/1, keepalive is only enabled in HTTP/1.1
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        chunked_transfer_encoding off;

        proxy_pass http://minio:9000;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        # Default is HTTP/1, keepalive is only enabled in HTTP/1.1
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        chunked_transfer_encoding off;

        proxy_pass http://minio:9001;
    }
}
```

Docker compose file:

```
  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
        - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
      - ../s3-bucket:/data
    env_file:
      - config/.env.minio.prod
    command: server /data --console-address :9001
```

Error from the internet browser:

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://s3.mysite.com/ws/objectManager. BrowserHandler.tsx:105:14
Error in websocket connection. Attempting reconnection... BrowserHandler.tsx:140:12
Websocket Disconnected. Attempting Reconnection... BrowserHandler.tsx:132:12
Websocket not available. BrowserHandler.tsx:126:14
Websocket not available.
```

I think there is something missing in the Nginx config file to reach both ports on Docker service. What I understand port `9001` is responsible for the console functionallity and port `9000` for data handling. But not sure how to proxy pass to both ports appropriately.

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Docker, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks @Turing85, was not sure where to ask, will repost the question on one of the suggested portal.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Let me know if you find a way, and I'll do the same

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this for a long time and was finally able to resolve it.

As far as I can tell, the key changes to make this work for me where:

- Manually specifying a `rewrite` directive (instead of relying on the Nginx proxy_pass+URI behaviour which didn't seem to work for me).
- Setting the `resolver` directive with short timeouts (so that rescheduling of services onto other nodes gets resolved).
- Setting `$upstream` to prevent DNS caching.

I have edited your config files below:

**nginx.conf**:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name s3.mysite.com;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name s3.mysite.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/s3.mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/s3.mysite.com/privkey.pem;

    # To allow special characters in headers
    ignore_invalid_headers off;
    # Allow any size file to be uploaded.
    # Set to a value such as 1000m; to restrict file size to a specific value
    client_max_body_size 0;
    # To disable buffering
    proxy_buffering off;

    # Use Docker DNS
    # You might not need this section but in case you need to resolve
    # docker service names inside the container then this can be useful.
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=10s;
    resolver_timeout 5s;

    # Apparently the following line might prevent caching of DNS lookups
    # and force nginx to resolve the name on each request via the internal
    # Docker DNS.
    set $upstream "minio";

    # Minio Console (UI)
    location /console/ {

        # This was really the key for me. Even though the Nginx docs say 
        # that with a URI part in the `proxy_pass` directive, the `/console/`
        # URI should automatically be rewritten, this wasn't working for me.
        rewrite ^/console/(.*)$ /$1 break;

        proxy_pass http://$upstream:9001;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        # Default is HTTP/1, keepalive is only enabled in HTTP/1.1
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        chunked_transfer_encoding off;
    }

    # Proxy requests to the bucket "photos" to MinIO server running on port 9000
    location /blog/ {

        # Redirect /blog/* requests to /photos/*
        rewrite ^/blog/(.*)$ /photos/$1 break;

        proxy_pass http://$upstream:9000;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        # To support websocket
        # Default is HTTP/1, keepalive is only enabled in HTTP/1.1
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        chunked_transfer_encoding off;
    }

    # Proxy requests to the Minio API on port 9000
    location / {

        proxy_pass http://$upstream:9000;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_connect_timeout 300;

        # To support websocket
        # Default is HTTP/1, keepalive is only enabled in HTTP/1.1
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        chunked_transfer_encoding off;

    }


}
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
minio:
    image: minio/minio
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
        - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
        - ../s3-bucket:/data
    #env_file:
    #  - config/.env.minio.prod
    environment:
        MINIO_SERVER_URL: "https://s3.mysite.com/"
        MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL: "https://s3.mysite.com/console/"    
        MINIO_ROOT_USER: minio
        MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: minio123
    command: server /data --console-address :9001 /data
```

HTH!